# is it possible to turn a unicode value into a char like you can with an ascii value?

Tags: c++

As the title states, I want to turn a Unicode value (not in hexadecimal form) into a char, for example, something like `(char)(945)` should turn into `α`, is this possible with the standard library?

Comment: You should be able to do it with `wchar_t` type. `char` type is not large enough to hold a value such as 913. Note that on Windows `wchar_t` is 16 bits wide, enough to handle Windows notion of Unicode, while Linux uses 32 bits.

Comment: Could you give a short example of what you want to do? There are a few slightly different things that you could mean and some code would help us know (and in your question, the value should be 945 or maybe you meant capital Α). Maybe you want `char32_t` or `std::wcout`+UTF-16 encoding or UTF-8 encoding

Comment: `913` is `Α` (Greek capital letter alpha). `α` has code `945` (Greek small letter alpha)

Comment: the standard library is very very limited when it comes to dealing with Unicode. Most applications use a proper unicode library like [icu](https://icu.unicode.org/)

Comment: Consider using [GNU unistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/). Read about [UTF8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: @jkb i dont get what you mean?

Comment: `char` is ultimately a 8-bit number. Large integers like `945` don't fit into one. You can turn it into multiple characters using one of the encodings (UTF-8, etc).

Comment: As HolyBlackCat said, numbers like `945` require more bits to represent them than the `char` type has available. The standard `wchar_t` --- wide character --- type has more bits available and can store such values.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's possible with the basic library so I just used a Unicode library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).